# Atom & Yii2 - How to add Yii2 Code Hints to Atom Text Editor?

Tags: php, documentation, yii2, atom-editor

Is it possible (and how) to add Yii2 code hinting to Atom Text Editor?

While searching for a question, I came across a YouTube video where the person had type hinting on SublimeText for Yii2 functions.

Video Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kg17wiJfGA8

A perfect example in his video, is at the 1:23 mark. It pops up 
`ActiveField field(Model $model, string $attribute, array $options = [])` and the documentation for it. In Aptana Studio, you imported the library (such as Yii) somewhere in the settings. It then pulled the code hints from the comments.

While the video wasn't for my problem, I was glad I stumbled upon it. I use Atom, and would love to have this. You are supposed to be able to hack and make Atom do whatever you want, how would I go about getting this added to Atom?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible, Atom is an editor not an IDE. I may be wrong.

Comment: By nature, anything is possible with Atom. Whether someone has created a plugin for it that does it, is another question. The point of Atom, is you can code it to do whatever you want. I just haven't ventured into creating my own plugins for it.